# Conversion from 'double' to 'System::TVarRec' is ambiguous

Tags: compiler-errors, clang, c++builder

I'm trying to compile some code in Embarcadero C++Builder using the BCC32C compiler, but I get an error:

> [bcc32c Error]: conversion from 'double' to 'System::TVarRec' is ambiguous

Comment: It's very difficult to explain why code you do not include isn't working properly. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was solved simply by casting

```
 VarRec v_double = (long double) 1.0;
 TVarRec v_longdbl = 1.0l;`
```

Comment: That is because [`TVarRec` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `double` as input](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec.Create), but it does have one for `const long double &`. But why are you using `TVarRec` at all? You are not supposed to be using `TVarRec` directly, unless you are manually manipulating the contents of a Delphi `array of const` function parameter. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?